# How can i find the name of student who has the highest average? Java

Tags: java

I have a simple project in java. 
the project is a program for a teacher who wants to enter the grades for his students (three grades for each student) with five private attributes `name`,`grade1`, `grade2`, `grade3`and `average` and three methods: `readGrades()`, `GetAverage(`) and `getName()`. I but them all but my problem is no matter what I did the output always gave me the average of the latest student I entered not the highest.I should also print his name not the average.
someone told me to use ArrayList but honestly I don't know how?? 
so if anyone can help me I'll appreciate it.
This is what i have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    private String name;
    private int grade1, grade2, grade3;
    private double average;

    void Setgrade1(int g1) {
        grade1 = g1;
    }

    void Setgrade2(int g2) {
        grade2 = g2;
    }

    void Setgrade3(int g3) {
        grade3 = g3;
    }

    int Getgrade1() {
        return grade1;
    }

    int Getgrade2() {
        return grade2;
    }

    int Getgrade3() {
        return grade3;
    }

    int readGrades() { //method that reads grades. 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int g1, g2, g3;
        String name;
        char choice;
        do {
            System.out.println(" --Please enter the student name: ");
            name = input.next();
            SetName(name);
            System.out.println(" --Please enter the first grade: ");
            g1 = input.nextInt();
            Setgrade1(g1);

            System.out.println(" --Please enter the the second grade: ");
            g2 = input.nextInt();
            Setgrade2(g2);
            System.out.println(" --Please enter the the third grade: ");
            g3 = input.nextInt();
            Setgrade3(g3);
            System.out.println(" Do you want to continue?  enter the number ");
            System.out.println(" 1- YES     2- NO ");
            choice = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        while (choice != '2');
        return choice;
    }

    void SetAverage(double avr) {
        average = avr;
    }

    double GetAverage() {
        average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
        return average;
    }

    void SetName(String name1) {
        name = name1;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class TestStudent1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.readGrades();
        student.GetAverage();
        double i = 0;
        double average = student.GetAverage();
        if (i < average) {
            i = average;

            System.out.println("THE HIGHEST AVG :" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. method names should start with a lower case charachter and also should be camel case so `Setgrade1` should be `setGrade1`

Comment: Also if you want to have *highest*, you should have more than one student

Comment: how can i do it then? I'm allowed to use one object only

Comment: Are you allowed to use one object or one class? If you store the values of a student in an object of type `Student`, then you have to produce multiple ones, one per student. You can then use an `ArrayList<Student>` in order to store all the students and compare then (maybe by sorting the list).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried debugging your homework assignment? If not, this is a great time to learn about debugging.

Comment: @deHaar  yeah I'm allowed to use only one object. So in the end i shloud use ArrayList<Student> ? sorry but how? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems in your code here are as follows:

1) It is giving you the output for the latest student is because you are modifying a single object all the time as your logic for entering more grades and name is inside the student itself which should be out.

2) To get the name and not the average you should call getName while printing.

3) To handle multiple students  you can take out the logic of asking `do you wish to continue` in your `main` method and make an `ArrayList` of students in the `main` method to handle multiple student objects or you can do it with other collections as well like

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

From here loop and add the student objects in the list using `students.add(studentObj)`.

Then to get the highest compare the average of the students objects by using getAverage and find the student with the highest average from the list and print it.

That will do it. Try some of it and if you are stuck let us know.

Comment: can you tell me the correct way to compare the AVG of the student object? I did all what you told me except this part, I didn't understand it...

Comment: There could be multiple ways of doing so a) you can create a list of all the averages by looping over the list of student objects and calling getAverage on each. Then you can get the Maximum of your new list by using Colllections.max(newList). b) you can create array for the average and the ways can go on. But I would say doing with the list as explained in point 'a' is easiest and quick.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You have only one instance object for that class, so, when you read data for more students, the next student will replace the data from the previous student.

In this case, to save all students and get information about all of them, is better use ArrayList, and push all new data to that list.
e.g:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in the end, you can get the average that you need.

Edit:

Code using ArrayList:

**Student class**

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int grade1, grade2, grade3;
    private double average;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGrade1() {
        return grade1;
    }

    public void setGrade1(int grade1) {
        this.grade1 = grade1;
    }

    public int getGrade2() {
        return grade2;
    }

    public void setGrade2(int grade2) {
        this.grade2 = grade2;
    }

    public int getGrade3() {
        return grade3;
    }

    public void setGrade3(int grade3) {
        this.grade3 = grade3;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public double calculateAverage() {
        return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a list of student
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int g1, g2, g3;
        String name;
        int choice;
        do {
            //Instantite a new object student
            Student student = new Student();

            System.out.println(" --Please enter the student name: ");
            name = input.next();
            student.setName(name);

            System.out.println(" --Please enter the first grade: ");
            g1 = input.nextInt();
            student.setGrade1(g1);

            System.out.println(" --Please enter the the second grade: ");
            g2 = input.nextInt();
            student.setGrade2(g2);

            System.out.println(" --Please enter the the third grade: ");
            g3 = input.nextInt();
            student.setGrade3(g3);

            System.out.println(" Do you want to continue?  enter the number ");
            System.out.println(" 1- YES     2- NO ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            student.setAverage(student.calculateAverage());

            //Push a new object to student list
            studentList.add(student);
        }
        while (choice != 2);

        //Get student object with the higher average
        Student higherStudent = Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getAverage()));

        System.out.println("THE HIGHEST AVG :" + higherStudent.getAverage() + "\n BELONG'S TO: " + higherStudent.getName());
    }
}
```

I have transfer the while code to main method, and create a new method to calculate the average, because the getAverage is how we will retrieve the value calculate.

Edit: Get higher average with **simple loop**

Replacing:

```
Student higherStudent = Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getAverage()));
```

By:

```
Student higherStudent = new Student();
for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        higherStudent = studentList.get(i);
    } else if(higherStudent.getAverage() < studentList.get(i).getAverage()) {
                    higherStudent = studentList.get(i);
      }
}
```

Comment: and how should I compare to get the highest AVG?

Comment: I have edited my comment with the answer. Any doubt you can ask.

Comment: it's work! THANK YOU SO MUCH! but could you please compare it by using a loop? because I don's think I'm allowed to use the Colllections.max(). sorry if i bothered you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you need to create multiple instances of student object in order to store the data of multiple students. What you did in your code is you will always replace your data with the last input. Here is an example of what you can do.

```
    Student student1 = new Student();
    Student student2 = new Student();
    Student student3 = new Student();
```

You will also need a data structure to store all the instances of student object, you can either use Array or ArrayList. You will then add every instance of the student object into your data structure. After that, you can compare the average among all the students in your array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove user interaction method `readGrades()` from data holder `Student` class. It should be outside. I think that you should not hold `average` as separate field. This is not big dial to calculate it every time whey you invoke `getAverage()` method:

```
public final class Student {

    private final String name;
    private int grade1;
    private int grade2;
    private int grade3;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGrade1(int grade1) {
        this.grade1 = grade1;
    }

    public void setGrade2(int grade2) {
        this.grade2 = grade2;
    }

    public void setGrade3(int grade3) {
        this.grade3 = grade3;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3.0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getGrade1() {
        return grade1;
    }

    public int getGrade2() {
        return grade2;
    }

    public int getGrade3() {
        return grade3;
    }
}
```

Second, do create separate method, that interacts with user (or probably other sources) to retrieved required number of students.

```
private static List<Student> getStudents() {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        char choice;
        Student student;

        do {
            System.out.print(" --Please enter the student name: ");
            students.add(student = new Student(scan.next()));

            System.out.print(" --Please enter the first grade: ");
            student.setGrade1(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.print(" --Please enter the the second grade: ");
            student.setGrade2(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.print(" --Please enter the the third grade: ");
            student.setGrade3(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.println(" Do you want to continue?  enter the number ");
            System.out.println(" 1- YES     2- NO ");
            choice = scan.next().charAt(0);
        } while (choice != '2');

        return students;
    }
}
```

And finally very simple client's code:

```
List<Student> students = getStudents();
students.sort((s1, s2) -> Double.compare(s2.getAverage(), s1.getAverage()));
System.out.println("THE HIGHEST AVG :" + students.iterator().next().getName());
```

Comment: sadly most of your code i didn't study it yet. So I can't use something that I didn't learn it.  And about the AVG it's required to me to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an alternate approach that doesn't use `List/ArrayList`. Since this is homework, I won't provide code.

Since the requirement is to find the student with the highest average, and you're collecting each student and three grades at a time, you only need to keep track of two instances of Student at any one time.  The one with the highest grade `bestStudent`, and the one being entered `currentStudent`.

After each student is entered, check to see whether `currentStudent`'s average is higher than `bestStudent`'s. If it is she's your new teacher's pet. Otherwise, discard. Keep in mind, you'll need to handle the first student a little bit differently.